# Chrome JS Profiler and "Not Optimized: Inlining Bailed Out" warnings

Tags: javascript, warnings, out, inlining

I have tried to run my app with the Chrome JS Profiler recording the CPU usage, and I've got a few warnings, ther were some "ForInStatement is not fast case", which I have fixed, but I am getting the "Inlining Bailed Out" warnings, for example in this code:

```
function display_loader(){
  for(i in obstacles){
    display(obstacles[i])
  }
}
```

This function basically creates an obstacles (display(obstacles[i]) draws a specific image of an obstacle - two separate functions for loading and for the code because of the "ForInStatement" warnings mentioned above).

The message "Inlining Bailed Out" appears randomly, especially when I play more than a minute, and it appears in either move_loader, display_loader or collision_loader functions. Sometimes does, sometimes doesn't.

Can you give me any word-explanation of ´what this message really means? I've read a lot of threads over the web and I understand the "ForInStatement" logic, but I have no clue about the Inlining Bailed Out.

Also, can you give me a hint of how I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Same problem here, no answers?

Comment: can you please add the code of the display function?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `bailout` means that the function **could not be optimized**. This can come from **unsupported JS features** like `try/catch` blocks, `for of`, etc. or because the optimization process hit certain limitations.

As [the docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/js-execution?hl=en) sums up:

> Not all functions can be optimized. Some features prevent the optimizing compiler from running on a given function (a “bail-out”)

[This article](http://floitsch.blogspot.ch/2012/03/optimizing-for-v8-inlining.html) series gives some good explanations. Basically, the Inlining is crucial for good performance. But functions are not systematically inlined, since it has a cost. Normally, only functions called many times are picked up for inlining.

So in your case, I guess there is something in your `display` function that prevents optimization. The message does not pop up directly because the function is not always/directly picked for optimization:

> One consequence of this optimization approach is that s**hort-running programs [...] don't exit their warm-up phase and don't get optimized**. In general it is not necessary to waste energy to optimize something that is only run for a very short time.
>
> Furthermore, note that V8 uses a non-deterministic sampling profiler to detect hot functions. **Performance can therefore vary wildly depending on which function is active during the profiling ticks**.

Further reading [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/). Hope this helps.